# Does this combination かもしれないけど...とか思ってんじゃないか always have the same meaning, as if it were an idiom?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> *グレーかもしれないけど、ギリギリセーフとか思ってんじゃないか？*

This line was spoken in a video. Here's added sentences for context.

> Detective:
> テレビ番組を勝手にアップロードしちゃダメだよな。
> お前そんなのも知らなかったんか？
> グレーかもしれないけど、ギリギリセーフとか思ってんじゃないか？
> 本当に違法なんだぞお前。

This has my brain twisted since
グレーかもしれない means something about it being a grey area, and
けど is an adverb meaning but; however.

I think the idea of the sentence might be that :
Uploading falls in a grey area, so you thought it was safe.

Even if I tried translating this sentence 20 different ways, I wouldn't know which one to pick since they all have different nuances.

> Since it might fall into a grey area, you thought you were playing it safe, huh?

> Even though it falls in a grey area, you thought it'd be like playing it safe, didn't you?

> Even though it falls in a grey area, you thought you'd be playing it safe, didn't you?

> It could be a grey area, you thought you could play it safe, huh?

> It could fall into a grey area, you thought it would be playing it safe, right?

> It may be gray area, but you thought it was just barely safe.

> It might be a grey area, you thought you were playing it safe, huh?

> It's probably a grey area, you thought you were playing it safe, huh?

> It probably falls in a grey area, you thought you were playing it safe, huh?

> It might fall into a grey area, you thought you were playing it safe, huh?

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that グレーかもしれないけど might be part of what the detective suspected the suspect thought?

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you very much for your reply. It sounds similar to the replies I received elsewhere: "It's kind of iffy, but no one's gonna catch me," right?" & "Are you thinking it is legally gray, but it's just barely safe, aren't you?" As always, I hope this question can be used as a reference for future language students, and all my posts are always open-ended, and future input/debate is encouraged. But I feel this question has been more than answered well enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid to say none of those 10 attempts are spot-on.

- "グレーかもしれないけど、ギリギリセーフ(だ)" as a whole is the quoted sentence corresponding to 思う. Let's not be deceived by the comma.
- セーフ in a context like this means "barely safe/acceptable" rather than "(perfectly) safe". ギリギリ intensifies this meaning. I suppose this is related to the fact that *safe* was initially introduced to Japanese as a baseball term. "セーフ!" on its own can mean "That was close!" See: [「ギリギリセーフ！」と英語でどういうの？](https://www.qqeng.com/blog2/study/do-that-was-close.html)

> You thought "(Legally speaking) it may fall in a grey area, but (practically speaking) I'd be barely safe", didn't you?